# How do I display a table from a database in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a class build from the database, called `RSS_Head`. One of its properties is a url to a rss-feed. I want to display the links in a table.

```
@using Pgsrssreader.Models
@model Pgsrssreader.Models.RSS_Head

<table>
            @{RSS_Head rsshead = new RSS_Head();}
            <tr>

                <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => rsshead.SUrl)</th>
            </tr>
```

Now I try a foreach loop to display the urls like this:

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SUrl)
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I get the error:

> Foreach statement can not operate on variables of type `Pgsrssreader.Models.RSS_Head` because `Pgsrssreader.Models.RSS_Head` does not contain a public definition of GetEnumerator

```
namespace Pgsrssreader.Models
{
      using System;
      using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class RSS_Head
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public RSS_Head()
        {
            this.RSS_Row = new HashSet<RSS_Row>();
            this.Rss_Category = new HashSet<Rss_Category>();
        }

        public int iRSSid { get; set; }
        public string SUrl { get; set; }
        public string sTitle { get; set; }
        public string sLink { get; set; }
        public string sDescription { get; set; }
        public string sLanguage { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> dBuildDate { get; set; }
        public string sCopyright { get; set; }
        public string sImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string sImageTitle { get; set; }
        public string sImageDescription { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> iImageHeight { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> iImageWidth { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> bAktiv { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> iDatumKorr { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> bDatumFinns { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> iTableIndex { get; set; }
        public string sTidning { get; set; }
        public string sCatFieldName { get; set; }
        public string sCatName { get; set; }
        public string sDateFieldName { get; set; }
        public string sDateReplace { get; set; }
        public string sRegexp { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> iPaperId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> iFailed { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public virtual RSS_Papers RSS_Papers { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<RSS_Row> RSS_Row { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Rss_Category> Rss_Category { get; set; }
    }   
}
```

**Edit: Solution**
I ended up creating a helper class in shared views:

```
public class Rsshelper
{
    private Rss_DevEntities _db = new Rss_DevEntities();


    public List<RSS_Head> Feeds()
    {
        List<RSS_Head> rss_head = new List<RSS_Head>();
        rss_head = _db.RSS_Head.ToList();
        return (rss_head);
    }
}
```

Then I wrote

```
 @{ 
                List<RSS_Head> rsslist = new List<RSS_Head>();
                Rsshelper rsshelper = new Rsshelper();

                rsslist = rsshelper.Feeds();




            }
    <table>

        @{if (rsslist != null)
            {

                foreach (var item in rsslist)
                {



                    <tr>
                        <td>

                            @item.SUrl
                        </td>
                     </tr>
```

to display the urls. There is probably a better solution out there so feel free to improve on mine :)

Comment: Your model `RSS_Head` does not look like a `List` implementation with enumeration support.

Comment: That's right it isn't a list.

Comment: If it isn't a list or any data structure that can be enumerated you cannot loop through it with a foreach

Comment: Well it should be a collection which impements `IEnumerable` interface. Or one of the readily availabe collections such as `List<T>`. `foreach` can repeat only on collections that are enumerable.

Comment: You can read this in order to understand about foreach: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288257(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Is there an easy way to turn it into a list, or build a list from it?

Comment: It depends on the data model. Can you post your RSS_Head class?

Comment: For that we need to see its code. Currently all we know that it is an object, which is practically nothing.

Comment: I updated my question with the RSS-Head class now

Comment: For now I really only need a list of the rss urls and the corresponding titles.

Comment: sUrl is just a string, you cannot iterate through it... if it contains just one element the loop has no sense, if it contains several elements (for example separated by a semicolon, or other splitter) you can split them to an array and then convert them to a list to being able to iterate through it.

Comment: But how do you expect to iterate through `sUrl` ?  Its  a string. And how can you iterate through the model when It is also not a list or IEnumerable?

Comment: I would guess that it contains a string for each datarow in the database?

Comment: I do not know what you have in `sUrl`. But if you want to get a list of `sUrl` from the database, either use a ViewModel or pass a list of `RSS_Head` to the View. Then you can iterate through the model and display the `Surl`

Comment: Class RSS_Head was created by MVC from the database, so I am pretty sure there is a way to get to all the urls through it. I just don't know how :)

Comment: If you want to get all the `RSS_Head` , then you should pass a list of `RSS_Head` to the View. And what is that you actually want to list ? `sUrl` or something else?

Comment: Ok... I'll guess that you're using something like Linq2SQL, then you should execute a query to your database and fill a IEnumerable<RSS_Head> with it, then you can iterate through that

Comment: Currently `public string SUrl { get; set; }` is just one string. Thus each `RSS_Head` contains a single `sURL` item, just as they have a single `sTitle`, `sLink`, and `SDescription`. Is it possible that you are planning to show a list of `RSS_Head`, not `sURL`?

Comment: I want to display a list of sURL, but it is ok if I get a list of RSS_Head too. Then I can just get sURL from that.

Comment: I tried a quick fix 
@model IEnumerable<Pgsrssreader.Models.RSS_Head>
But then the model is null

Answer (score 1):

Mainly Entity framework is the best methos for such operations
First grab the database record in list. You can mention this in your model,

**Model :**

```
public IEnumerable<modelname> AnyName{get; set;}
```

**Logic Code(controller):**

```
Public ActionResult Youaction()
{
  modelclass yourmodel= new modelclass();
  yourmodel.AnyName=Fun1();
}
public IEnumerable<modelName> Fun1()
{
   databaseclass dbobj1= new databaseclass();
   tableclass tbl= new tableclass();
   modelName yourmodel= new modelName();
   return(var v in dbobj1.table1 select new model
          modelproperty1=v.tablevalue1,
           .,
           .,
      modelpropertyforUrl=v.tablevalueForUrl
).ToList();

}
```

**your view :**

```
<table>
@foreach(var item in AnyName)
{
  <tr>
<td>@item.modelpropertyforUrl</td>
  </tr>
}

</table>
```